InnoDB How to lock a db- row with script1.php and delete it with script2.php
please tell me, how to solve the following issue.
javascript.js gets data from givemedata.php which selects data from DB and shall lock the selected row to make it invisible for other queries with a query like
SELECT * FROM data_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
then javascript.js processes the data an sends some of it back to storemydata.php which shall then delete the locked row.
The issue is how to tell the database that the row shall keep being locked even if givemedata.php has ended and until storemydata.php wants to delete the locked row and is there any kind of handle which could be stored for example in $_SESSION to tell ?

The lock is removed when the transaction ends, so it can't persist after the end of the script.

Cannot have two separate connections involved in the same transaction.  So, what you have described sounds impossible.

 In   givemedata.php:

    <?php
session_start();
include 'db_connection.php'; // Make sure you have a db_connection.php that sets up your PDO connection

try {
    $conn->beginTransaction(); // Start a new transaction

    // Lock the row for update
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM data_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($row) {
        // Store the locked row's identifier in the session
        $_SESSION['locked_row_id'] = $row['id'];
    }

    // Send the data to the client
    echo json_encode($row);

    // Commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

In storemydata.php:
    <?php
session_start();
include 'db_connection.php'; // Ensure you have your PDO connection here

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['locked_row_id'])) {
        $lockedRowId = $_SESSION['locked_row_id'];

        // Start a new transaction
        $conn->beginTransaction();

        // Delete the locked row
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM data_table WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $lockedRowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Commit the transaction
        $conn->commit();

        // Clear the locked row id from session
        unset($_SESSION['locked_row_id']);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("No row locked.");
    }

    echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
?>

in db_connection.php:
    <?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db = 'your_database';
$user = 'your_username';
$pass = 'your_password';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
?>

